# how to get which one of the clicked element in ng-repeat from object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I want to implement the changeThing function without using the $event but instead send the object , this function should return the clicked html element ?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in objs"> {{obj.name}} <a on-click="changeThing(obj)"></a> </li>
</ul>
```

in directive link

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    function changeThing(obj) {
       how to get the html element the has been clicked on without using $event 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The obj that u pass is just a JSON object you cannot get the DOM element with it.

If u need the DOM Element you should use $event.target

But what excactly are you trying to archive?

Comment: Thank you Dear Robin

I'm trying to type the changeThing function to be used from many different places, not only by clicking the element